# Why isn't this module displaying in the django 1.4 admin interface?

Tags: python, django

directory stucture

```
tutorial/tutorials
turotial/tutorial
```

tutorial/settings.py

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
'django.contrib.admin',
# Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
# 'django.contrib.admindocs',
#'domains'
'tutorials'    
)
```

tutorials/admin.py

```
from tutorials.models import Tutorial
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(Tutorial)
# Create your views here.
```

tutorials/models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Tutorial(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: You may already have tried that but did you restart your webserver ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things to help finding the problem:

- Do you have `admin.autodiscover()` in your urls.py
- Have you run syncdb
- Have you tried to open `manage.py shell` and import the model to see if there are errors.

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not have an entry in your INSTALLED_APPS setting for this app.

Comment: I updated the question with the settings, could it be that the settings is in the tutorial directory and not the tutorials directory?